# Target _blank doesn't open in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using the following code in my ionic project to open the new system browser and post the values. For some reason the the new windows doesn't open.

I don't get any kind of errors. The link does open but in self browser. I want it to open in the android system browser.

```
var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
mapForm.target = "_blank";    
mapForm.method = "POST";
mapForm.action = "http://www.example.com/api/form.php";

// Create an input
var firstname = document.createElement("input");
var lastname = document.createElement("input");
var address = document.createElement("input");
var email = document.createElement("input");

firstname.type = "text"; firstname.name = "firstname"; firstname.value = "John";
lastname.type = "text"; lastname.name = "lastname"; lastname.value = "Doe";
email.type = "text"; email.name = "email"; email.value = "user@example.com";

// Add the input to the form
mapForm.appendChild( firstname );
mapForm.appendChild( lastname );
mapForm.appendChild( email );

// Add the form to dom
document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

// Just submit
mapForm.submit();
```

Comment: have you tried with _system?

Comment: @Marko Yes I have tried `_system` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `_system` will work.

Here is an example:

```
window.open(url,'_system','location=yes'),!1;
```

Comment: Sorry, how do I implement this with my current code?